# NodeRED http-response node: How to stop NodeRED adding charset to content-type?

Tags: http-headers, node-red

I need to build a http proxy for a jpeg image inside NodeRED. My goal is that the browser does get all page resources in the dashboard from the NodeRED server. And the image is only available from another server.

I tried this abstract flow:

```
http-in -> http-request -> function node -> http response
```

In the function node I set the headers:

```
msg.headers = {
    "content-type": "image/jpeg",
    "content-disposition": "inline; filename=\"myimage.jpg\""
}
```

The problem is, that the browser gets these headers (excerpt):

```
content-type: image/jpeg; charset=utf-8
content-disposition: inline; filename="myimage.jpg"
```

Where the hell is `charset=utf-8` coming from and how to stop NodeRED adding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not mention what `msg.payload` is set to in your flow.

If the `msg.payload` you pass to the HTTP Response node is a String, the content type gets the charset parameter added. This isn't deliberate behaviour of Node-RED - but something happening in the underlying http/express framework.

If `msg.payload` is a Buffer object, then no such parameter is added.

Comment: Perfect hint!  I just had to set the output of the http request node set to binary and reduce my function node code to ```msg.headers["content-disposition"]="inline";```. Now it works. +1

Answer (score -1):

charset=utf-8, is added by node-red to define the standard there will be no issue if headers added charset on it.